# Generate values for y from a linear equation and plot on a graph

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to plot the following function for values of x between -10 and 10

*=2.52+7+4.2*

[Click here to see the Maths Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5ju.png)

I have managed to create an array    consisting of 100 equally spaced values between -10 and 10 using the function linspace from numpy.

I'm struggling with how I can substitute the X values generated from the linspace function into the equation to find values for Y and then plot these on graph with a dashed black line instead of a solid blue line.

I know how to do this on paper, but I am struggling to understand which libraries to use in Python for this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 100)

y = 2.5*x[0]**2 + 7*x[0] + 4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 100)
y = 2.5*x**2 + 7*x + 4.2

plt.plot(x, y, '--', linewidth=2, markersize=12)
plt.show()
```

It should output this graph

[image]

Please write me back if you further face any issues. Cheers...